# Drive.DriveApi.query returns inconsistent result

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I've been trying to retrieve a file list from Google Drive, but the Drive.DriveApi.query ends up with very inconsistent response.

I have a file directory structure like this:

```
+ myRootFolder
|
+--+ folderA
   +-- cover.jpg
   |
   + folderB
   +-- cover.jpg
   +
   ...
```

and I want to get "cover.jpg" files of all folders:

```
private void fetchFolders(final GoogleApiClient gClient) {
    // 1: get a reference to myRootFolder
    //
    Query query1 = new Query.Builder()
        .addFilter(Filters.eq(SearchableField.TITLE, "myRootFolder"))
        .build();

    Drive.DriveApi.query(gClient, query1).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult result1) {
            MetadataBuffer mb1 = result.getMetadataBuffer();
            DriveId rootDriveId = mb1.get(0).getDriveId();
            mb1.close();

            DriveFolder rootFolder = Drive.DriveApi.getFolder(gClient, rootDriveId);

            // 2: get a reference to all folders
            //
            rootFolder.listChildren(gClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult result2) {
                    List <DriveId> folders = new ArrayList<DriveId>();

                    MetadataBuffer mb2 = result2.getMetadataBuffer();
                    for (Metadata md : mb2) {
                        folders.add(md.getDriceId())
                    }
                    mb2.close();

                    // 3: get cover.jpg of all folders
                    //
                    for (DriveId folderId: folders) {
                        Query query2 = new Query.Builder()
                            .addFilter(Filters.eq(SearchableField.TITLE, "cover.jpg"))
                            .addFilter(Filters.in(SearchableField.PARENTS, folderId))
                            .build();

                        Drive.DriveApi.query(gClient, query2).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResult(DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult result3) {
                                MetadataBuffer mb3 = result3.getMetadataBuffer();
                                assert mb3.getCount() == 1; // <<<<<<<<< FAIL HERE
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

The assert should pass since all folders have one cover.jpg file, but the actual result is, some folder passes the test and others fails... It's confusing. Also, the result varies between devices (some device fails in folderA but other device fails in folderB).

What am I missing?

---

EDIT 2014-07-18:

Wanted to mention that those files can be retrieved with both iOS SDK and Javascript (Node.js) API without any problems. Just don't work with Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Drive.DriveApi.requestSync(GoogleApiClient client)
```

May help.

Answer (score 0):

The Android SDK will only return files for which the app is authorized  (i.e. files that have been created by the same app ID, or files which have been previously opened by the app ID).

You can verify which files your app is authorized for by using the Drive web UI.  Go to https://drive.google.com > Gear menu > Manage apps > yourapp Options > View all files this app is authorized to access.

If it's the case that the "cover.jpg" files aren't authorized for the folders with errors, try picking "cover.jpg" using the same app ID.

Comment: Thanks, but there is nothing listed in the option menu (http://i.gyazo.com/13bac981df651223d4c80e7806d544e0.png) Also, those file can be retrieved by iOS app using the exact app ID without problems, as I mentioned in the edited question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try viewing the files that your application is authorized to access by using the path provided by p00ya using the old version of Google Drive (`Gear menu > Leave the new Drive`).

It seems like the new version of Google Drive does not yet implement this feature.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you missed something. I got this here:
https://developers.google.com/drive/android/queries

Once a Query object has been constructed it can be executed on the entire file system using Drive.DriveApi as follows:

```
      Drive.DriveApi.query(googleApiClient, query);
```

This query starts in the My Drive (the root) folder and recursively traverse the entire filesystem, returning all entries matching the Filters expression tree.

Do you really need to find that specific folder name and traverse? Or would doing a direct query on 'cover.jpg' work?